# Should Quotation-Ending Period Be Comma Unless Sentence Ending?

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotations, periods

Now I'm checking [Quotation Marks](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/quotation-marks/) article by [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/). The article, for example, introduces

> “There was a storm last **night,”** Paul said.

which uses a comma at the end of the quoted sentence, and

> John said, “I really hate when it’s hot **outside.”**

which uses a period instead. Because the article doesn't tell, I wonder whether the period at the end of the second example—even if it is a sentence-ending period—must be changed to a comma if I invert or extend the sentence as follows.

> “I really hate when it’s hot **outside,”** John said.

or

> John said, “I really hate when it’s hot **outside,”** but it seemed his dog didn't.

Comment: You have evidently learned the rules. Your examples are just fine. Don

Comment: 'Yes, this is so' is the only response that this question needs.

Comment: Thank you for reading and confirming this question.